# Ignore error in SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am getting an "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblUsers when trying to copy data from an excel file to sql db using SSIS.

Is there any way of ingnoring this error, and let the package continue to the next record without stopping?

What I need is if it inserts three records but the first record is a duplicate, instead of failing, it should continue with the other records and insert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a System variable called `propagate` which can be used to continue or stop the execution of package .

1.Create an `ON-Error` event handler for the task which is failing .Generally it is created for the entire `Data Flow Task`.

2.Press `F4` to get the list of all variables and click on the Icon at the top

[image]

to show `System Variable`.By default `Propagate` variable will be True ,you need to change it to false ,which basically means that SSIS wont propagate the Error to other component and let the execution continue

[image]

```
Update 1:
```

To skip the bad rows there are basically 2 ways to do so :-

1.Use Lookup

Try to match the `primary key column values` in  source and destination and then use `Lookup No Match Output` to your `destination`.If the value doesn't match with the destination then insert the rows else just skip the rows or redirect to some table or flat file using `Lookup Match Output`

Example

[image]

For more details on Lookup refer [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/) article

`2.`Or you can  redirect the error rows to a flat file or a table .Every SSIS Data Flow components has a Error Output .
For example for Derived component ,the error output dialogue box is

[image]

But this condition may not helpful to u in your case as redirect error rows in destination doesn't work properly .If an error occurs it redirects the entire data without inserting any row in the destination .I think this happens because OLEDB destination does a `bulk insert` or inserts data using `transactions`.So try to use `lookup` to achieve your functionality .

Comment: The package is now completing with success even though there is an error but it is not adding any records. Could this be something to do with a transaction?

Comment: I thot you need to skip the component on error so gave you the suggestion to use `Propagate` variable.I have updated my answer now